# Change theme of button on click

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-theme

I set a theme for my button. This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/theme_blue_color"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp">

        </corners>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
       android:color="#05f">

       </stroke>
    </shape>
```

Then I want that image change on click. So I create another file (I named it reverse and I put it in drawable folder). Then in java I set:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btn(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_blue_color));
                btn(R.drawable.reverse);
            }
        });
```

I works correctely! But I want that happened as happened when you normally click a button (change color onpress and then it stay with originally color).
How can I do this with theme? Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
  <shape   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/red"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#05f" />

  </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
  <shape   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/theme_blue_color"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#05f" />
  </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

In this example you have two different shapes. The first one has the pressed state, with a solid red color. Use it as background for your button

Comment: Ok thanks! And how can I change foreground color with selector?